# CefSharp chromium browser font issue

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I am working on a wpf application. I am using Cefsharp chromium browser instead of wpf webview. It support all font but its not clear (give blur screen).

Answer (score 0):

We've noticed this issue as well. We found that it goes away if you use WinForms instead of WPF.

Have you tried [CefSharp.Wpf](http://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf/)?